# Cavitation damage to car throttle body

Tags: renault, clio, throttle-body

Really quick yes or no, *do I need to replace the throttle body on my Clio*? It's exhibiting signs of cavitation damage, but I don't know if it's bad enough to replace or not.

[image]

Comment: This looks like a casting fault not cavitation...

Answer (score 1):

Considering the metal is coming apart, yes you need to replace it. This is with the thought: *Where does the metal go when flaking off?* The answer, directly into your engine, where it can cause damage to the cylinders, pistons, valves, and possibly seats. Replacing the TB now will prevent future engine damage.

Comment: Being soft zinc , there is a fairly good chance it did not damage anything. ... But there is a small chance it is aluminum, which would be more likely to cause damage.

Comment: @blacksmith37 - *Any* FOD has the potential to create damage to the engine ... doesn't matter if it's soft zinc or harder aluminum. Even as soft as zinc is, it stands the chance of scoring a cylinder wall or damaging a ring or ring land. Albeit the zinc is *less likely* but still capable of causing issues. If you want a TB which looks like that and likely to flake off more metal into your engine, I'm good with that. Me, not a chance.

Comment: Although not stated, I was also considering the small size of the bit. However , I don't disagree that about any solid can cause damage.